# Remove brown/yellow resin around electronic components

Tags: glue

A fuse socket in my Edifier sub-woofer stopped connecting (I accidentally damaged it when I was replacing a fuse) and I want to replace it.

When I opened the rear panel I found out all high voltage components are in black rubber tubes and are sealed by some brownish resin.

Is there some way beside bruteforce to remove it?

Image for reference:
[image]

Comment: Why would you want to remove it?

Comment: The rubber tubes are heat-shrink tubing, if you were wondering. You can replace it easily when you replace the fuse holder.

Comment: Be sure to replace the tubing with something similar. It's there because the insulation on the low voltage wiring is not safe to be in contact or close proximity with the mains wiring. Safety certification requirement.

Comment: Acetone usually works well to soften up some types of epoxy, however, it will wreck havoc on everything else so use it carefully. It may eat your electronics too so be careful in your use of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clue : this is a subwoofer. That goop is there to stop things rattling. (The "rubber" tubes look like heatshrink sleeving; easy to buy and fit as part of your repair).

Only remove what you have to, to replace a broken component. I'd probably use a woodworking chisel in a similar situation.

And you'll want to replace that goop with something similar - maybe hot-melt adhesive would work,  or epoxy if that doesn't. to stop your repair rattling.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up removing that goop with a pocket knife and pliers. Afterwards I wrapped new parts with silky insulating tape and I don't hear any rattling :)